# How to increment/decrement for each item with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to create a counter for each item in a list in React. I want each to be incremented or decremented individually depending on what the user clicks on. This issue is that all counters increment and decrement on click of a single element, but I would like only the clicked element's counter to change. My code below

```
 const syndicateList = [
    {
      _id : 1, 
      price: 500,
      shares: 130,
      lines: 1000,
    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      price: 700,
      shares: 140,
      lines: 650,
    },
  ];

  const [num, setNum] = useState(1);
  const [disble, setDisable] = useState(false);

  const incrementCount = ()=> {
    setNum(num + 1);
    setDisable(false);
  };

  const decrementCount = ()=> {
    if (num > 1) {
      setDisable(false);
      setNum(num - 1);
    } else {
      setNum(1);
      setDisable(true);
    }
  };


return(
<>
  {syndicateList && syndicateList.map((syndicate, i)=>(
   <div key={i}>
   <div>{syndicate.price}</div>
    <button
    className="btn btn-danger px-3"
    disabled={disble}
    onClick={()=> decrementCount(syndicate._id)}
   type="button" >
              -
            </button>
          </span>
          <span>{num}</span>
         
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger px-3"
              onClick={()=>incrementCount(syndicate._id)}
              type="button"
            >
              +
            </button>
 </div>
  
))
</>
```

)

Comment: the number to increment/decrement is ```num```?

Comment: You passed syndicate._id as a parameter to incrementCount and decrementCount, however the functions do not use these parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing the following,

```
const [num, setNum] = useState(syndicateList.map(item => 1));
  const [disble, setDisable] = useState(syndicateList.map(item => false));

  const incrementCount = (index)=> {
    num[index]++;
    setNum([...num]);
    disable[index] = false;
    setDisable([...disable]);
  };

  const decrementCount = (index)=> {
    if (num[index] > 1) {
      disable[index] = false;
      setDisable([...disable]);
      num[index]--;
      setNum([...num]);
    } else {
      num[index] = 1;
      setNum([...num]);
      disable[index] = true;
      setDisable([...disable]);
    }
  };
```

Then in the return part,

```
return(
<>
  {syndicateList && syndicateList.map((syndicate, i)=>(
   <div key={i}>
   <div>{syndicate.price}</div>
    <button
    className="btn btn-danger px-3"
    disabled={disble[i]}
    onClick={()=> decrementCount(i)}
   type="button" >
              -
            </button>
          </span>
          <span>{num[i]}</span>
         
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger px-3"
              onClick={()=>incrementCount(i)}
              type="button"
            >
              +
            </button>
 </div>
  
))
</>);
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider this example, you will get a clear idea about the concept

```
import React, {useState} from "react"


function App() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)


function increment() {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1)
}

function decrement() {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount - 1)
}

return (
    <div>
        <h1>{count}</h1>
        <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
        <button onClick={decrement}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
)}

export default App
```

Comment: Hello, this does not reply to the answer, he wants a list of counter and how to manage them. He is not asking about how to use useState with a basic counter (it's already done in the post he made)

Comment: Yes exactly, the counter works well with the code I shared but it increment/decrement all the items which is not what I want, I want it to increment only the item the user click